# Bind to a custom property with Nancy

Tags: c#, json, binding, nancy

I have a class with this property:

```
public string FeatureString { get; set; }
```

However I receive this in my JSON:

```
"feature_string":"someText"
```

The names do not match, due to the underscore, and thus this property is not being bound.
Giving it an attribute:

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "feature_string")]
```

Doesn't seem to help.

Is there, and if there is how, a way to bind with Nancy to a property with a name that differs from the JSON?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is supported out of the box.
Two options I can think of:

- Build a dedicated request DTO with the structure the request actually has. Nancy can also bind to private inner classes. Your module could contain the `feature_string` as a field. Field binding is also supported by Nancy. When you data-bound the inner request class, you can map to your real object, e.g. using Automapper. You still need an object having the same structure as the JSON, but at least you can hide it a bit that way.
- https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/5521941 here is a dynamic model binder which allows binding an incoming JSON to a `dynamic`. Again using Automapper, you could bind from the dynamic object to your actual object, which should work without explicit configuration. For the `feature_string`, you could define one explicit mapping rule.